Overriding comparison operators for double values within std::variant
I have a class method that compares std::variants according to the currently chosen relation:
bool Result = false;
auto CachedValue = ...;         // std::variant<std::wstring, double, int>
const auto& FirstValue = ...;   // std::variant<std::wstring, double, int>
if (auto ValIndex = CachedValue.index(); ValIndex == FirstValue.index())
{
    switch (m_Relation)
    {
    case RELATION::EQ: Result = (CachedValue == FirstValue); break;
    case RELATION::NE: Result = (CachedValue != FirstValue); break;
    case RELATION::GT: Result = (CachedValue >  FirstValue); break;
    case RELATION::LE: Result = (CachedValue <= FirstValue); break;
    case RELATION::LT: Result = (CachedValue <  FirstValue); break;
    case RELATION::GE: Result = (CachedValue >= FirstValue); break;
    . . . . .
    }
}
return Result;

However, I would like to use the "epsilon-based" comparison for double values contained inside the variants. But all my attempts to implement this lead to a multiple increase in the code size and loss of readability. Is there a way to implement this compactly in C++ 17?
First, my task has nothing in common with numerical calculations; otherwise, using of std::variant would be inappropriate. Second, I have a mathematical background, and am fully aware about the elementary properties of equality and ordering. And third, I'm not asking how to compare floating-point values. I'm asking about what seems to me an interesting programming exercise: How to override the default comparison of POD types that make up std::variant without increasing too much the code size and losing readability?
Edit: As for the concern that the way I phrased the problem violates elementary properties of equality and order, believe me, I know what I'm doing. The code that compares std::variants should only be called by my application if the variants contain the same type (the same index()). If it is not so somehow, the whole application behavior is horribly wrong and the application should be aborted.
Probably, to emphasize this point, it would be better to throw when the compared variant's types are not the same, instead of the attitude "garbage in - garbage out".

I think I misunderstood your question so I removed my answer. Can you show the exact epsilon-based comparison that you would like to use (for equality checks I presume)?

Note that "nearly equals" (i.e., epsilon-based) comparisons are tricky. If a nearly equals b and b nearly equals c, you cannot conclude that a nearly equals c. That will lead to many problems if you aren't exquisitely careful.

Something along these lines, perhaps: return std::visit([&](const auto& arg){ return myCompare(m_Relation, arg, std::get<decltype(arg)>(FirstValue ); }, CachedValue); Now you can write overloads of myCompare for various types as needed; in particular, an overload taking two double parameters.

Comparing floating point numbers is very very tricky. Usually it makes sense to know what kind of value ranges you can expect to be able to select a good range (having one "epsilon" usually isn't good enough). Read this Comparing Floating Point Numbers, 2012 Edition. This is my goto resource I use for reference when dealing with floating point numbers.

Use std::visit with overload pattern. You can feed the overload with instances of std::less too.

@IgorTandetnik I have thought in this direction but haven't been able to bring it to full implementation. Could you please elaborate your suggestion in more details? Perhaps as an answer?

@Red.Wave Could you please elaborate this in more details? It seems close to what Igor Tandetnik suggested.

Show what you've tried, preferably in the form of a [mcve]. I'm too lazy to turn your incomplete snippet into a compilable example.

Using std::varaiant accessors leads to both unsafe and irreparable code. std::visit is the proper way to use a variant: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit . In your case, std::less<>{} can be one of the overloads.

You can std::visit multiple variants, but you have to deal with every combination. In your case that is simple: for same type, do comparison, for different types, return false.
return std::visit([m_Relation](auto && Cached, auto && First){
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<decltype(Cached)>, std::decay_t<decltype(First)>>) {
        return myCompare(m_Relation, Cached, First);
    } else {
       return false;
    }
}, CachedValue, FirstValue);

You then write overloads of myCompare for your types
bool myCompare(RELATION rel, double lhs, double rhs) {
    // comparison with epsilon
}

template <typename T>
bool myCompare(RELATION rel, const T & lhs, const T & rhs) {
    // normal comparison
}

N.b. you might want to reconsider whether std::wstring NE double should be false, because at the moment you don't have !(a EQ b) == (a NE b) etc.

Perfect! I knew there had to be something like this, but I don't have enough knowledge in modern C++ to do it myself. I had to search and read additional C++ material on the Internet to fully understand this solution. By the way, I haven't found a satisfactory explanation of std::visit with overload pattern, so your solution is also a good example to learn from.
Regarding your warning at the end, see my edit.

@Ilia the short explanation is that std::visit can apply to any number of variants. auto parameters are a shorthand for templated types, the lambdas call operator is instantiated with every combination of types, and we use if constexpr to hide myCompare when it can't be called. The overloaded pattern is a class that inherits from multiple lambdas (or other function objects), using member function overload resolution to pick which one to call. It's literally just template<class... Ts> struct overloads : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };

Thanks for the clarification. The only thing I still understand in general but not in detail is the expression std::decay_t<decltype(Arg)>. In my case, Arg is decleared as std::variant&&, and the exact result of decltype(Arg) is not clear for me. Then, logically, std::decay_t should return the type currently contained in std::variant, but I couldn't find even a mention of this on the Internet!

@Ilia decltype(Cached) and decltype(First) are going to be references, and const corresponding to if CachedValue or FirstValue are. They aren't going to be variant &, they will be std::wstring &, double & and int & in the different calls. std::decay_t does the standard conversion that a pass-by-value function call would do to arguments, i.e. remove the reference (and const)

I think I'm starting to get it. The goal of std::visit is not visiting different variants in a container (the most common and, as it turns out, misleading example on the internet). Rather, std::visit treats std::variant itself as a container of types and visits every type inside that container. It all makes sense now.

@Ilia visit needs to be able to call operator() on the visitor with every combination of the types the variant contains, which one it does depends on what is in the variant. it doesn't produce a std::wstring from somewhere when the variant contains a double

Here is my final (and working) solution, inspired by @Caleth's answer. In case someone is interested.
In the header file:
class Attribute : public AttrBase
{
    .....
    struct attr_val_t : std::variant<std::wstring, double, int> 
    {
        using base_t = std::variant<std::wstring, double, int>;
        attr_val_t() : base_t() {}                      // default
        attr_val_t(const base_t& base): base_t(base){}  // copy
        attr_val_t(base_t&& base) : base_t(base) {}     // move
        attr_val_t& operator=(const base_t& base)       // assignment
                { *(base_t*)(this) = base; return *this; }
        bool Contains(const attr_val_t&);   // for string values
        bool NContain(const attr_val_t&);   // for string values
    };
    friend bool operator==(const attr_val_t&, const attr_val_t&);
    friend bool operator!=(const attr_val_t&, const attr_val_t&);
    friend bool operator> (const attr_val_t&, const attr_val_t&);
    friend bool operator< (const attr_val_t&, const attr_val_t&);
    .....
};

In the source file:
inline bool DoubleEQ(double left, double right)
{
    static const auto eps = double(4*FLT_EPSILON);  // just under 0.5*10^-6
    double diff = fabs(left - right);
    return diff <= eps || diff <= eps*(std::max)(fabs(left),fabs(right));
}
inline bool DoubleNE(double left, double right) { return !DoubleEQ(left, right); }
inline bool DoubleGT(double left, double right) { return left > right && !DoubleEQ(left, right); }
inline bool DoubleLT(double left, double right) { return left < right && !DoubleEQ(left, right); }

bool operator==(const Attribute::attr_val_t& left, const Attribute::attr_val_t& right)
{
    return std::visit([](auto&& L, auto&& R)->bool
    {
        using Ty = std::decay_t<decltype(L)>;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Ty, std::decay_t<decltype(R)>>)
            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Ty, double>) return DoubleEQ(L, R); else return L == R;
        else
            throw std::logic_error("Mismatched variant types!");
    }, left, right);
}
bool operator!=(const Attribute::attr_val_t& left, const Attribute::attr_val_t& right)
{
    return std::visit([](auto&& L, auto&& R)->bool
    {
        using Ty = std::decay_t<decltype(L)>;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Ty, std::decay_t<decltype(R)>>)
            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Ty, double>) return DoubleNE(L, R); else return L != R;
        else
            throw std::logic_error("Mismatched variant types!");
    }, left, right);
}

and the same for operators > and <.
